# I am having trouble in displaying date beside the entered todo element. What is wrong with changeDate() function?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Entered todo is shown but the date is not being shown. Am i using any wrong command?? On entering a data, date should be shown on the left of the todo, just below the input area.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('demo');
var list2 = document.getElementsByTagName('todos');

function store(ele) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    changeText();
  }
}

function changeText() {
  var data = document.getElementById('todo').value;
  if (data != '') {
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    changeDate();
  }
}

function changeDate() {
  var d = new Date();
  var dates = document.createElement("div");
  dates.className = "myClass";
  dates.innerHTML = document.createTextNode(d.toDateString());
  list2.innerHTML = dates;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    Your todos
  </h1>

  <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add a new todo and hit enter" onkeydown="store(this)">
  <div class="todos">
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So for each element you would like to get the date when it was added?

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a new question...

Comment: yes, just to the left of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your JS has an issue. The `list2` is a `HTMLCollection` and there's no `.innerHTML` for that. You need to use:

```
list2[0].innerHTML
```

You don't even need that. The date issue is because of the Date Object incorrectly being set / inserted.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('demo');
var list2 = document.getElementsByTagName('todos');

function store(ele) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    changeText();
  }
}

function changeText() {
  var data = document.getElementById('todo').value;
  if (data != '') {
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    changeDate(list);
  }
}

function changeDate(which) {
  var d = new Date();
  which.innerHTML += d.toDateString();
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    Your todos
  </h1>

  <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add a new todo and hit enter" onkeydown="store(this)">
  <div class="todos">
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: I want date to be shown to the left of the todo, in the same row

Comment: @aQwusjargon Instead of `+=` use: `which.innerHTML = d.toDateString() + which.innerHTML;`

Comment: even, this didn't help sir!! Date keeps on printing in the first line below input and the todos goes on printing below that

Comment: After `entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));` I wrote `entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dt.toDateString()));` and `list.appendChild(entry);` and was successful in getting date to the immediate left of todo, but I want the date to the extreme left of todo, rather than immediate left, what should I do?

Comment: @aQwusjargon Do me a favour. Put everything you have till now in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and send me the URL, okay?

Comment: Thanks, but with your help and some more searches, I was able to do what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your dedicated participation and help!!

Comment: okay, I would love to motivate people like you to keep their spirits high

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
function changeText() {
  var data = document.getElementById('todo').value;
  if (data != '') {
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    changeDate(list);
  }
}
```

try this:

```
function changeText() {
  var data = document.getElementById('todo').value;
  if (data != '') {
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    changeDate(list); //call this before appending data
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    list.appendChild(entry);

  }
}
```

and CSS:

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: on shifting the position of _changeDate(list)_, the dates are written one after another after which the todos are written, they too one after another, in the same row. On keeping the position of _changeDate(list)_ same, the todos with respective dates are being written in the same row, how to change the row?